# Best approach of defining endpoints for pagination retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I was thinking which should be the preferred way of defining endpoints in Retrofit2 for pagination.

Should we separate the endpoints or should we define only one endpoint method and pass `page=null`?

```
@GET("/search/users")
Observable<FetchUserResponse> fetchUsers(@Query("q") String uname,
                                         @Query("sort") String followerspage);

@GET("/search/users")
Observable<FetchUserResponse> fetchUsersPaginationCall(@Query("q") String uname,
                                                       @Query("sort") String followerspage,
                                                       @Query("page") int page);
```

or

```
@GET("/search/users")
Observable<FetchUserResponse> fetchUsers(@Query("q") String uname,
                                         @Query("sort") String followers,
                                         @Query("page") String page);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjustments must happen on the API itself, it must set a default on a page if it is null or missing on the query param. You should define **one end point** only for this.